# How to change page number positions for with active \maketitle

Tags: header-footer, titles, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I am trying to **change the position of the page numbers from the bottom center to the bottom right**. I tried using the `fancyhdr` package which seemed to be the most recommended way to solve this issue. However, when I used it along with the `\maketitle` command the `fancyhdr` package has no effect on the first page. On the second page the positioning of the numbers does move to the bottom right, but I do not like how it changes the format for the header. Below is a simplified version of my code. Any recommendations?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\title{Some Random Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

Some random words.    
\newpage
Some random words on second page.

\end{document}
```

[image: first page]

[image: second page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page where `\maketitle` has effect uses the `plain` page style. Redefine it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}

% redefine the plain page style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% no rule above!
  \fancyhf{}\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage}%
}

\title{Some Random Title}
\author{Author Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some random words.

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. This did fix the problem on the first page, now the page number is on the bottom right. However, if you add another page (`\newpage Some random words on the second page`), the ruler is still present at the header. I tried making edits to your code to fix this, but couldn't figure out a solution.

Comment: @dahiana Add `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` also after `\pagestyle{fancy}`.